# Выделение деепричастного оборота

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

Преодолеть эти испытания можно(,) только имея полное храбрости сердце.

«Имея полное храбрости сердце» – деепричастный оборот, значит, нужно ставить запятую. Но ее как-то совсем не хочется ставить, что вызывает сомнения. Нужна ли там запятая и почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Преодолеть эти испытания можно, **только имея полное храбрости сердце.**

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113

3. Деепричастный оборот, в начале которого стоят частицы ***только, лишь***, интонационно не отделяется от предшествующей части предложения (при чтении пауза перед ним не делается), но запятая перед ним обычно ставится: **Понять это произведение можно, только учитывая условия его создания**; Выучить иностранный язык можно, лишь постоянно занимаясь им.

Пример:

Попасть в ресторан тогда можно было, только имея связи или за деньги. [Маша Трауб. Плохая мать (2010)]